# OpenCL segfaults but gives different error with GDB

Tags: c++, gdb, opencl

I have a very simple OpenCL kernel that I'm trying to run

```
void kernel point_within(global const int* pointsX, global const int* pointsY, global int* center, global int* extents, global bool* output) {
   output[get_global_id(0)] = (abs(pointsX[get_global_id(0)] - center[0]) <= extents[0]) && \
                              (abs(pointsY[get_global_id(0)] - center[1]) < extents[1]);
};
```

This is what I'm trying to run it with in C++

```
///
//  Attempt to create the program object from a cached binary.  Note that
//  on first run this will fail because the binary has not yet been created.
//
inline cl::Program CreateProgramFromBinary(cl::Context context,const std::vector<cl::Device> devices, const char* fileName)
{
    std::ifstream file(fileName, std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate | std::ios::in);

    uint32_t size = file.tellg();
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    char* buffer = new char[size];
    file.read(buffer, size);
    file.close();

    cl::Program::Binaries bin{{buffer, size}};

    std::vector<cl_int> binaryStatus;
    cl_int *err;
    cl::Program program = cl::Program{context, devices, bin, &binaryStatus, err};

    if(err != CL_SUCCESS) {
       std::cout<<" Error building: "<<program.getBuildInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG>(devices[0])<<"\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    return program;
}

///
//  Create an OpenCL program from the kernel source file
//
inline cl::Program CreateBinaryFromProgram(const cl::Context context,const std::vector<cl::Device> devices, const char* readFileName, const char* writeFileName)
{
    std::ifstream file(readFileName, std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate | std::ios::in);

    uint32_t size = file.tellg();
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    char* buffer = new char[size];

    file.read(buffer, size);
    file.close();

    cl::Program::Sources sources;

    // kernel calculates for each element C=A+B
    std::string kernel_code(buffer);
    sources.push_back({kernel_code.c_str(),kernel_code.length()});
    cl::Program program{context,sources};
    if(program.build(devices)!=CL_SUCCESS){
       std::cout<<" Error building: "<<program.getBuildInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG>(devices[0])<<"\n";
        exit(0);
    }
    std::vector<char*> output = program.getInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BINARIES>();
    std::vector<size_t> output_sizes = program.getInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BINARY_SIZES>();
    std::ofstream outFile (writeFileName, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    outFile.write(output[0], output_sizes[0]);
    outFile.close();
    return program;
}

devices = loadDevices();
context = cl::Context{devices};
cl::Program program = CreateProgramFromBinary(context, devices, "HelloWorld.cl.bin");

cl::Buffer buffer_PointsX(context,CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,sizeof(int)*10);
cl::Buffer buffer_PointsY(context,CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,sizeof(int)*10);
cl::Buffer buffer_Center(context,CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,sizeof(int)*10);
cl::Buffer buffer_Extends(context,CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,sizeof(int)*10);
cl::Buffer buffer_Output(context,CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,sizeof(bool)*10);

int PointsX[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
int PointsY[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
int Center[] = {0, 0};
int Extends[] = {1, 2};
bool output[]{false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false};

//create queue to which we will push commands for the device.
cl::CommandQueue queue(context,devices[0]);

//write arrays A and B to the device
queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(buffer_PointsX,CL_TRUE,0,sizeof(int)*10,PointsX);
queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(buffer_PointsY,CL_TRUE,0,sizeof(int)*10,PointsY);
queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(buffer_Center,CL_TRUE,0,sizeof(int)*10,Center);
queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(buffer_Extends,CL_TRUE,0,sizeof(int)*10,Extends);


//run the kernel
cl::Kernel kernel_add=cl::Kernel(program,"point_within");
kernel_add.setArg(0,buffer_PointsX);
kernel_add.setArg(1,buffer_PointsY);
kernel_add.setArg(2,buffer_Center);
kernel_add.setArg(3,buffer_Extends);
kernel_add.setArg(4,buffer_Output);
queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel_add, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(10),  cl::NDRange(2));
queue.finish();
```

This is the output that I get

`Using platform: Intel(R) OpenCL
Using device: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4590S CPU @ 3.00GHz
Running program...
Segmentation fault`

So I ran it through GDB

`3 errors generated.
 Error building: Compilation started
1:5:1: error: unknown type name 'opt'
1:5:4: error: expected identifier or '('
1:5:16: error: source file is not valid UTF-8
Compilation failed`

I get a very different output signaling an error compiling (which was never the case with just plain running the program)

I'm not sure how to debug this any further. I removed the compiling from GDB and directly ran from the binary and this was the line giving me trouble

```
0  0x00000000004034c9 in cl::Program::Program(cl::Context const&, std::vector<cl::Device, std::allocator<cl::Device> > const&, std::vector<std::pair<void const*, unsigned long>, std::allocator<std::pair<void const*, unsigned long> > > const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >*, int*) ()
1  0x0000000000403c10 in CreateProgramFromBinary(cl::Context, std::vector<cl::Device, std::allocator<cl::Device> >, char const*) ()
2  0x0000000000401ed6 in main ()
```

How would I go about debugging this issue/ What is the issue?

Comment: Well, according to the stack trace your problem is in the portion of your code which was omitted "for brevity", specifically the function `CreateProgramFromBinary`. In addition you're passing a _global work size_ of 0 (`cl::NullRange`), so even if compilation worked your kernel wouldn't actually run. OpenCL provides a fairly robust error reporting mechanism, using which you can even retrieve the output log - including warnings and errors - from runtime compilation. In general, and _particularly_ when tracking a failure, error values should be checked for every OpenCL operation.

Comment: @pandorafalters my mistake, I thought I included that portion. I just added it  Also, I was playing with changing various variables. Just updated to give it a global work size of 10 and local work size of 2. Also included the line on which it does fail and the function. I think I do check for compilation errors but maybe I'm not doing it correctly?

Comment: A program that segfaults and when run under gdb runs normally, usually is due to uninitialized variables or race conditions. I would recommend first, compiling your program with -g3 to get lines that problems occurred. second, use Valgrind and check for errors. Valgrind will tell if any memory address is used without being set. third, if Valgrind still leaves you with doubts, you can use Valgrind gdb server to stop the program when a memory error occurs and debug it.

Comment: @cjds Are you perhaps calling the wrong function? You've added (twice) `CreateBinaryFromProgram` which appears to do what you _want_, but still not `CreateProgramFromBinary` where your error originates.

Comment: @pandorafalters I'm an idiot. Copypasta'd the wrong thing. Re-copied the right one

Comment: On a further note, the vector returned from `cl::Program::getInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BINARIES>` is _also_ filled with dynamically-allocated memory. You'll need to iterate over that vector to `delete[]` each element to avoid another memory leak. For such reasons I tend to avoid OpenCL's C++ interface. The OpenCL 2.0 version uses `vector<vector<unsigned char>>` instead, which is much safer, but cl2.hpp has a number of issues with Nvidia's OpenCL implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing an uninitialized pointer (`err`) to `cl::Program`'s constructor, *and* then in your error test you're not dereferencing it. Either initialize it, dereference in your test, and delete it:

```
cl_int *err = new cl_int; // <-- initialize pointer
cl::Program program = cl::Program{context, devices, bin, &binaryStatus, err};

if(*err != CL_SUCCESS) { // <-- dereference pointer
    // ....
}
delete err; // <-- release memory
```

or use a non-pointer object and pass the address to `cl::Program`:

```
cl_int err; // <-- not pointer
cl::Program{context, devices, bin, &binaryStatus, &err}; // <-- pass address

if(err != CL_SUCCESS) {
    // ....
}
```

---

Also, `buffer` needs to be released in both `CreateProgramFromBinary` and `CreateBinaryFromProgram`:

```
delete[] buffer; // <-- note `[]`
```

As a general rule, add a matching `delete` *immediately* when you write `new`. It's much easier to find an improperly-placed `delete` than to find a *missing* one.

Comment: If you're up for it I have a similar problem with the next step on the chain https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53938591/opencl-load-program-from-binary

Comment: @Trass3r Although that doesn't work too well when you need a C string.

Comment: Why wouldn't it?

Comment: Hm, you're right. I was still focused on cases like `cl::Program::getInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BINARIES>` where the callee creates and allocates the string(s) into a container.